# is there an easy way to refresh a region in marionette?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I cannot seem to find a way to refresh a region of the page.  I have a drop down select option that has the ability to add a new item to that drop down through a modal dialog.  I want to redraw that region of the page that has that select option with the new item in it.  I can't seem to find a way to refresh that portion of the page in marionette or backbone.  I know I could call

```
location.reload();
```

but I assume there is a better way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a collection to hold your drop-down items, and then use a  Marionette.CompositeView to render the drop-down.
You can then add items to the collection, and call the CompositeView.render() function.

Comment: can you put a compositeView in an itemView?

Comment: No, it's the other way round.  Put ItemViews in your CompositeView.  Have a look at my blog entries around Marionette and Typescript for some samples :  [typescript-using-backbone-marionette-and-rest-webapi-part-1](http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2014/03/22/typescript-using-backbone-marionette-and-rest-webapi-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `show` method of the region.

```
var Layout = Marionette.Layout.extends({ regions: {yourRegion : '#my-region-id'} });
var yourlayout = new Layout
```

On change of dropdown event, create a new view  and render it inside the region with show method.

```
view = new Marionette.ItemView()
yourlayout.yourRegion.show(view)
```

Note: 1 region can render only one "view" at a time.Running show on the region will automatically close the previous view and render new view inside it.

Answer (score 0):

For adding new item, use `CollectionView` or `CompositeView` and then add your new add in the collection.

```
  // Item view
ItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: '#itemTemplate',
  // wrap the view with `tr` instead of `div`
  tagName: 'tr'
});

// Collection view
CollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  // Specify the itemView to render each item
  itemView: ItemView,
  // wrap the view with `tbody` instead of `div`
  tagName: 'tbody'
});


var collection = new Backbone.Collection([{id: 1, name:'Joe'}, {id:2, name:'masan'}]);

var view = new CollectionView({
  collection: collection
});
```

When you want to add new item, add it to collection.

```
collection.add({id:3, name: 'kumar'});
```